# C++ template class design with varying method return types

Tags: c++, templates

c++ design question

simplified example

```
template <typename T>
class Thing
{
    T value;
public:
    T get() { return value; }
};

template <typename T>
class Box
{
    Thing<T> thing;
public: 
    T get() { return thing.get(); }
};
```

Now I need to store different types of Box, like

```
Box<string>, 
Box<matrix>, 
etc
```

(where none of the T classes are related) in a container. Clearly this isn't possible, since T isn't the same for each type of Box. I can't create an abstract superclass since the return type of T varies and there is nothing in the get() parameters that could distinquish which get to use, if I somehow provide alternative implementations.

How to solve this is a reasonable way. Sure I could add multiple get()s in the abstract class but this doesn't seem very C++ ish. At some point I will have to check isThisAString, isThisAMatrix, the question is what's the most reasonable design, assuming I might need to add specialized Box subclasses in the future but still maintain a set of methods similar to get() which are based on the template parameter.

Comment: When you take the items out the container how will you know what their type is?

Comment: I'm reading about new c++ features like type_traits but nothing jumps out at me yet. I'm thinking maybe of returning a tuple or a class which contains the value and the type that the value is. Obviously the caller will have to interpret the value correctly. I'm just trying to find the modern way to model this in c++.

Comment: *Why* do you need to store this supposedly unrelated types in a *single* container?

Comment: Think of a spreadsheet program. Each cell might be a string or a number or a formula, etc. In C you might cast everything to a void* and have an enum but that isn't very C++ like.

Comment: Then each type must be convertible to a string, or *printable*. If you need a heterogeneous container, you can use a common base class, but that should only provide the polymorphic behaviour (print), not some class-specific behaviour like `get`. You can do this ad-hoc inside a class that holds the container (with a private class template `Box` deriving from some `BoxModel` base class).

Comment: If I were only interested in printing then this would work; but I need to process these different values as their own type. I am trying to investigate the 'any' listed in the below answer, or some variation thereof. C++ is so much fun, there are many solutions to any problem, but most of them are bad.

Comment: Unrestricted unions look promising - http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2544.pdf. There are implemented in clang so I might use this.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking is called "type erasure". There are several implementations :

- qt's [QVariant](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qvariant.html)
- boost's [any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/any.html)

Comment: Is there anything outside of requiring boost or qt?

Comment: Hmm, I found this article which is the basis of any ; http://www.two-sdg.demon.co.uk/curbralan/papers/ValuedConversions.pdf

Comment: @ahwulf No idea. If you don't find other implementation, implement your own. Or copy boost's any.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I went for the unrestricted union technique. The container has to hold values of different types but the entire container is always one type or another, currently a double or a std::string. I wanted one class which hid all the switch(type) statements inside.

Like:

```
class TValue
{
TBlockType type;
union
{
    TNumber aNumber;
    TString aString;
};
...
```

Once created the type does not change. The container of these only holds one type once created. But there is only one value type class. The only tricky parts were you need to create some explicit methods as the compiler deletes the built in versions due to std::string being non trivial, and in one case of a default constructor I had to set the union to null before creating a default string.